# What does target "_help" do?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm having hard time to find information related to `target="_help"` on the Internet. So, when I have an `HTMLAnchorElement` like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_help"></a>
```

I can see that this thing is actually behaving like `target="_blank"`, but anything else?

Could not find anything on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). Also no mention on the [HTML5 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) and detailed [W3C Browsing Context](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name-or-keyword) page.

Comment: If it has no defined meaning (which it doesn't appear to have), it's just going to open a new window with the name `_help` (where supported)

Comment: More generally, you may name the window the name you want (with limitation). But nothing really works if you use "tatrget" or "tagrte"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target):

> This attribute specifies where to display the linked resource. In
>   HTML4, this is the name of, or a keyword for, a frame. In HTML5, it is
>   a name of, or keyword for, a browsing context (for example, tab,
>   window, or inline frame).

That means that click on a

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_help"></a>
```

instructs `iframe` named `_help` to set `src` value to the value of `href`. The example below loads youtube video:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE" target="_help">Help</a>
<iframe name="_help"></iframe>
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/juwavodedi/edit?html,js,output).

On a side note, this feature looks pretty obscure, I did not know about it before your question.

Answer (score 3):

As mdn says:

**target**

This attribute specifies where to display the linked resource. In HTML4, this is the name of, or a keyword for, a frame. In HTML5, it is a name of, or keyword for, a browsing context (for example, tab, window, or inline frame). The following keywords have special meanings:

> _self:

Load the response into the same HTML4 frame (or HTML5 browsing context) as the current one. This value is the default if the attribute is not specified.

> _blank:

Load the response into a new unnamed HTML4 window or HTML5 browsing context.

> _parent:

Load the response into the HTML4 frameset parent of the current frame or HTML5 parent browsing context of the current one. If there is no parent, this option behaves the same way as _self.

> _top:

In HTML4: Load the response into the full, original window, canceling all other frames. In HTML5: Load the response into the top-level browsing context (that is, the browsing context that is an ancestor of the current one, and has no parent). If there is no parent, this option behaves the same way as _self.

So, if you use any other key except these 4 keys (_self, _parent, _top, _blank), it opens a blank window, and gives a name with the key you wrote on the target attibute to that window.

You can check:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target